# Post on Facebook without Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried googling answer for this question but I could not find a solution.

I am creating an android app which has a simple Activity with a Edittext view and POST button in it. If I write something in the textbox and click on the POST button, application should post the text on my facebook wall (Assume I already have username and password in my code).

Basically I don't want to open Facebook app UI for posting rather it should happen in background when I click on my custom UI POST button.

Comment: You need to use the Android Facebook SDK for that and ask for the right permission to post on Facebook.

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#custom) first, and then ask a concrete question about coding if you run into problems implementing this.